# Visual C++ system command batch file

Tags: command-line

When I type the name of a batch file on the command line, it executes just fine, but when I run a Vis C++ program which uses the `system("gen.bat")` command, it doesn't execute it!

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
int ret = system("gen.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the full path of the batch file like this:

```
int ret = system("C:\\folder_name\\gen.bat");
```

Comment: Yes, the program assumes the batch file is located in the same folder which the program was run, thus it is a good idea to put in the entire path of the batch file each time